# How to use list of numpy arrays to train ML algorithm?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, bioinformatics

I'm trying to develop a machine learning algorithm using LinearSVC and another one using Convolutional Neural Networks to classify DNA sequences.
I've had to one hot encode the DNA sequences and then I stored the resulting arrays for each sequence in a list.
But when I do the train-test split step I wasn't able to use it.

My DNA sequences are like this (not my real dataset, which is way bigger, just to exemplify. All the sequences are in the file 'seqs_for_test.fasta'):

> >TE_seq1
>   CCATAAACTATCTAAATAAGCACTTTTCTGGCTCTCTGGCCCCCCTTCTTCTTTTTGGGAAGGTGACAG
>   AGGGTAAAAGGGCTCTCTGCCGTGCGAGGCTCCTCACAGACACACAGCAAGAAAGAAGCGCCGCGCAGCA
>
> >TE_seq2
>   GATAGCCCCTCTCCCAGCCCCAGTCTGATCCCTAACCCTAACTCCACGGCTCCTGTCTCTACCCCCGTCT
>   CTTTCTTCTTGTACCCTAGTCCCCCAGATCATTAGCTCCCTGCTCGGGCCCAGGGTTTTAAGAGAAGCCC
>
> >TE_seq3
>   TGACTCAAGTCATGCTACCCAGCCCCGTCTTCTTAAAAATGAGACATGTTGAGACACCCTGCTTTTCGCC
>   TACAAACACATCCATTCTCTATACTTAGTCTTATTTAAATTCTATCCTCTGTATGTCTAGTCCTGGGGGT
>
> >RD_seq4
>   TGCTCGCCCCCCAGGAAGTGCAGAGACCGCCTGGGTGTGACTGTTTTTAGGCCTAACAAAGGCACAGAAA
>   CACCCGTGCGGTCTCTGTATCCCCTGGAGGTATTTCTCCCCATTAGTTTGCTTGACACTAAGTTTTTAAA
>
> >RD_seq5
>   TAAAAAAAGCTTATTAAGTCCCTAGAACCTGGGACCTATCTACCCAAGTTTTAAAACCTTACTTTTAAGG
>   CTACATTTTTTTATTTTGACTGTTTTACCATAAGGTCACATATAGGAAACCCCCACTGTCCTAATAAAAA
>
> >RD_seq6
>   CTAATCTCCTGTTGGCTGACTTACATCAGTTTGGGAAGTTGTTCATGATGACTCTGCGACGATCAAGAAG
>   GACCAGGACTCTCCCTGGACACCTCAGGGACTTCTTGCTGGAGGGCACCATACATCAGTTTGCCAGCAAA

Here is my code for LinearSVC:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
from numpy import argmax
from Bio import SeqIO
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


with open('../fasta/seqs_for_test.fasta') as fasta_file:  # Will close handle cleanly
    identifiers = []
    sequences = []
    for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(fasta_file, 'fasta'):  # (generator)
        identifiers.append(seq_record.id)
        sequences.append(seq_record.seq.lower())


s1 = pd.Series(identifiers, name='ID')
s2 = pd.Series(sequences, name='sequence')

# Gathering Series into a pandas DataFrame and rename index as ID column
fasta_frame = pd.DataFrame(dict(ID=s1, sequence=s2)).set_index(['ID'])
fasta_frame


label_serie = pd.Series()
fasta_frame.insert(1, "label", label_serie)

# Transposable element (TE) == 0; Random (RD) == 1.
fasta_frame.loc[fasta_frame.index.str.contains(r'TE_'),'label'] = 0
fasta_frame.loc[fasta_frame.index.str.contains(r'RD_'),'label'] = 1
fasta_frame


# empty list to store ohe array sequences
res_arr = []
for index, row in fasta_frame['sequence'].iteritems():
    # integer encode
    label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
    integer_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(row)
    # print(integer_encoded)
    # binary encode
    onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
    integer_encoded = integer_encoded.reshape(len(integer_encoded), 1)
    onehot_encoded = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(integer_encoded)
#     print(index)
#     print(onehot_encoded)
    # append ohe arrays
    res_arr.append(onehot_encoded)

y = fasta_frame['label']
# y

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(res_arr, 
                                                    y, 
                                                    test_size = 0.20, 
                                                    random_state=42)

# print(x_train)
# print(y_train)
# print(x_test)
# print(y_test)

from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
modelo = LinearSVC()
modelo.fit(x_train, y_train)
previsoes = modelo.predict(y_test)
acuracia = accuracy_score(y_test, previsoes) * 100
print("accuracy was %.2f%%" % acuracia)
```

I've tried to reshape, np.vstack and other ways but got no success.
How can I use the list of arrays as my training set?

Error message:

> ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.

Comment: Please include the exact error message.

Comment: Can you please post some small sample data to recreate the error? Without that or the actual error message it's hard to help

Comment: @IanQuah I posted above the samples. They are the sequences of A's, T's, G's and C's and the name with the '>' are the identifiers of each sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the SVM expects for each training example a fixed number of n features of dimension 1 and then tries to find a separating hyperplane in this n-dimensional feature-space. If you one-hot-encode your DNA-sequences of length m, you actually get m features of dimension 4. The LinearSVC implementation is not adapt to this situation (I am not sure if SVMs are in general applicable to features which are not one-dimensional, how should a space look like which is spanned by arbitrary-dimensional features?).

If you want to use sklearn's SVM implementations, you have to find a work around "formaly" reducing the dimension of your features to one. One possibility would be to **flatten your sequence representation**. I.e. starting from one DNA-sequence of dimension [140, 4] you create a flattened representation of dimension [560, 1] through concatenating the one-hot representations in the same dimensions.

Maybe an **example** is illustrative:

Given an example DNA-sequence "AC" is one-hot encoded to [[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0]]. Then you have to flatten the input to [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0] that you can train an SVM on DNA-sequences of length 2.

Why does this work?

The SVM will have 8 weights (ignoring bias terms). The first weight will weight the importance of adenine occurring as the first nucleotide. The second weight will weight the importance of having cytosine as the first nucleotide. The fifth weight will weight the importance of adenine occurring as the second nucleotide and so forth. Now, if the "AC" DNA-sequences comes along and we want to classify it, all weights are ignored except for the weights corresponding to adenine occurring as the first nucleotide and cytosine as the second nucleotide.

If your DNA-sequences are not all of a fixed length, you will have to **zero-pad** them. This means appending to their flattened sequence representation zeros until they are as long as the longest sequence in your dataset.

Comment: Nice! Got it! But about padding the sequences, adding the zeros won't make the algorithm mistakenly considerer the zeros as more cytosines (as in your example) leading to a bias?

Comment: Given a SVM for DNA-sequences of length two. If we now have an example DNA-sequences of only "A", one-hot encoded to [[1, 0, 0, 0]], we have to flatten it and append four zeros which will result into [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]. As only adenine occurs as the first nucleotide, all weights will be ignored except the weight corresponding to adenine occurring as the first nucleotide.

As the weights in an SVM are multiplied with the feature values and then summed up for a decision, the contribution of certain weights is zero if the respective feature is set to zero => no bias should be introduced